# String Issue in Python

Tags: python

I would like to understand why one program of mine is giving error and one not where as I am applying same concept for both of them.

The program that is giving error:

```
greeting = "test"
age = 24
print( greeting + age)
```

Which is true and it should give error because of incompatible variable types being concatenated. But this same behavior I was expecting from the below code as well where as it is giving proper result. Why is it so?

```
print("Please enter your name: ")
myname = input()
print("Your name is " + myname)

print("Please enter your age: ")
myage = input()
print("Your age is: " + myage)

print("Final Outcome is:")
print(myage + " " + myname)
```

Comment: The second program has only strings involved. You have the right idea that incompatible types can lead to an error.

Comment: `input` can only return a string because you type characters. It returns `'24'`, not `24`.

Comment: Do you have python 2 or 3? Because `raw_input()` in Python 2.x and `input()` in Python 3.x

Comment: Does it mean that value in myage variable is a string variable?

Comment: `input()` reads input as strings only.

Comment: I have python 3

Comment: Thank you Austin for the confirmation. Now, if I want to convert it into numeric value. What should I do? I know about str() which converts numeric to string but how to do vice versa?

Comment: Try this : `print(str(myage) + " " + myname)`

Comment: @GurmeetKaur. `int(myage)`

Comment: Great. Thanks for the help @MadPhysicist Got the point(y)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`input()` returns a string, even if the user enters a number.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Now, if I want to convert it into numeric value. What should I do? I know about str() which converts numeric to string but how to do vice versa?

Comment: for example int(input())

Comment: Great. Thank you for the help xhancar. (y)

Answer (score 2):

By default the input function in Python returns a string type. So when you enter the age, it is not being returned to your program as an int but rather a string. So:

```
print("Your age is: " + myage)
```

Actually looks like:

```
print("Your age is: " + "24")
```

Comment: Great. Thanks for the help. (y)

Comment: @GurmeetKaur, if you believe that this, or the other answers, answers your question, please click the green check mark on the left.